# Why does this regular expression give these extra characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex

I'm making a timer that counts up. A base time is created and then the difference between now and the base time is calculated.

I then make that difference a date, turn it into a string and extract the time in seconds, minutes and hours from it.

Code looks like this:

```
$scope.time = Date.now() - timeStart; // total elapsed time in ms
$scope.date = new Date($scope.time);
$scope.preDisplay = $scope.date.toUTCString();
$scope.timeDisplay = $scope.preDisplay.match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/);
```

The problem is $scope.timeDisplay shows up looking like this:

```
["00:00:00"]
```

I don't get where the square brackets and quotation marks are coming from. This is in angularjs, if I use JS or JQuery they aren't there.

What is going on?

Comment: They're not extra characters at all, it's because the value is an array as that's what `match()` returns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matches (`.match`) return an array of matching elements. Try accessing it using the first `0`th index:

```
$scope.timeDisplay = $scope.timeDisplay[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

its from this: `.match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/);`

`.match` returns an array of matches, in this case that one, just access directly using the index: `$scope.timeDisplay[0];`